# A valid React element or null must be returned following FlatList Tutorial

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html says:

{item.key}}
/>

So I did:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import styles from '../../Styles.js';

export default class MyMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return 
      <FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
  }
}
```

and I get that error in title.

[MuiThemeProvider.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125399/muithemeprovider-render-a-valid-react-element-or-null-must-be-returned) and 
[React.js A valid React element (or null) must be returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44060793/react-js-a-valid-react-element-or-null-must-be-returned)

say the cause of this is not returning 1 element;

In my code I return the one  as the documentation specifies.

Comment: Make sure you're including `import { FlatList } from 'react-native'`

Comment: Yes, if I wasn't doing that I wouldn't have gotten the error and instead would have gotten unrecognized "FlatList"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap FlatList with parantheses like this.

```
return (
  <FlatList
   data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
   renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
  />
)
```